# Accessing MDB file from Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, odbc

Just wondering what the best way to access read only information form a Microsoft Access file in a Rails 3 application would be, I know I could convert the data to CSV and then do a manual import into Postgres or SQLite but this data is ever changing as it is used in a business application at my work place and this would mean doing an import a few times a day.

If anyone could point me to a solution then it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I would do the export/import if I expected any load at all on the MS Access database. My own experience is that I am likely to bump up against limits to how well it scales in a situation like this. YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commercial cross-platform odbc drivers for MS-Access I think, but nothing open-source that can reliably read/write (and I could have used them once or twice in the last few years).

If you are on Windows you should presumably be able to use ODBC with a .MDB compatible driver. If not, you might be able to use MS-SQL server as a proxy (there's the "express" free version) or perhaps a java/perl proxy ([jackess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) / [DBD::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/lib/DBD/Proxy.pm)) but none of these are going to be a simple plug+play solution.

If you're committed to Access then something like [EasySoft's driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html) might be the simplest solution. Worth the money if it works well, but I've no direct experience with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I ran into this problem myself this week and managed to resolve access to an .mdb database from rails using the mdb gem as per:
https://github.com/jkotchoff/heroku_rails_microsoft_access_mdb_example